# to buy laptop for ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will buy a laptop for ROS. Which laptop is suitable for this. I want to setup 12.04 version of ubuntu . Then i will make localization corobot. Please help me !
Another question is that; Is suitable for ROS toshiba laptop. I can not setup ros on toshiba laptop. Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203712/to-buy-laptop-for-ros/) by [ayana](https://answers.ros.org/users/21064/ayana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a laptop from [ZaReason](http://zareason.com/shop/Laptops/) for work, which I use almost exclusively for ROS development. It wasn't cheap, but they were one of the few places I found that sold Linux laptops with an 8-core i7 and nVidia graphics. When I got it, it was slightly behind the cutting edge, a bit heavier and bigger than the best out there...which I guess is to be expected for a linux-specific laptop.

We've just recently gone from Ubuntu 12.04/Hydro to 14.04/Indigo. I haven't had a problem with it yet, and will likely buy from them again when the time comes (especially after watching some of my colleagues wrestle with video card driver problems on their ThinkPad and Alienware laptops).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1